# Google In-App billing V2 testing restore transactions

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, blackberry-android

I am working on Android-runtime for Blackberry In-app billing, they support Google In-app billing version 2, so i need to use version 2 and not version 3.

Mine item is MANAGED.

I stuck in testing restore transcations part.

1) How to test it ?

2) Can we test with "android.test.purchased", if so how?

3) How is the flow of restore transaction (already purchased item)?.

4) As per my understannding onPurchaseStateChange is called once when we request for purchase and once we are restoring the purchased item. is my understanding correct?

I have looked into the official developers website but i am little bit confused.

here the major code part that i am stuck.

```
 private class DungeonsPurchaseObserver extends PurchaseObserver {
        public DungeonsPurchaseObserver(Handler handler) {
            super(BlackBerryInAppPurchaseActivity.this, handler);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBillingSupported(boolean supported, String type) {
            if (Consts.DEBUG) {
            Log.i(TAG, "supported: " + supported);
            }
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " billing supported: " + supported, 2000).show();
            if (type == null || type.equals(Consts.ITEM_TYPE_INAPP)) {
            if (supported) {
                restoreDatabase();
            } else {
                showDialog(DIALOG_BILLING_NOT_SUPPORTED_ID);
            }
            } else {
            showDialog(DIALOG_SUBSCRIPTIONS_NOT_SUPPORTED_ID);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPurchaseStateChange(PurchaseState purchaseState, String itemId, int quantity, long purchaseTime, String developerPayload) {
            if (Consts.DEBUG) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onPurchaseStateChange() itemId: " + itemId + " " + purchaseState);
            }
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onPurchaseStateChange() itemId: " + itemId + " " + purchaseState, 2000).show();
            if (purchaseState == PurchaseState.PURCHASED) {
                    //Update the UI -unlock app 
            updateUI();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Purchased Update the Ui " + purchaseState, 2000).show();
            mOwnedItems.add(itemId);
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hiding the button as the item is purchased " + itemId + " " + purchaseState, 2000).show();
            }
            //mOwnedItemsCursor.requery();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SKU IS " + mSku, 2000).show();
            if (itemId.equals(mSku)) {
            switch (purchaseState) {

            case PURCHASED:
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " Purchased itemId: " + itemId + " " + purchaseState, 2000).show();
                break;

            default:
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " Item NOT Purchased itemId: " + itemId + " " + purchaseState, 2000).show();
                break;

            }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onRequestPurchaseResponse(RequestPurchase request, ResponseCode responseCode) {
            if (Consts.DEBUG) {
            Log.d(TAG, request.mProductId + ": " + responseCode);
            }
            //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "request.mProductId " + responseCode, 2000).show();
            if (responseCode == ResponseCode.RESULT_OK) {
            if (Consts.DEBUG) {
                Log.i(TAG, "purchase was successfully sent to server");
            }

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "purchase was successfully sent to server" + responseCode, 2000).show();
            logProductActivity(request.mProductId, "sending purchase request");
            } else if (responseCode == ResponseCode.RESULT_USER_CANCELED) {
            if (Consts.DEBUG) {
                Log.i(TAG, "user canceled purchase");
            }
            logProductActivity(request.mProductId, "dismissed purchase dialog");
            } else {
            if (Consts.DEBUG) {
                Log.i(TAG, "purchase failed");
            }
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "purchase failed" + responseCode, 2000).show();
            logProductActivity(request.mProductId, "request purchase returned " + responseCode);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onRestoreTransactionsResponse(RestoreTransactions request, ResponseCode responseCode) {
            if (responseCode == ResponseCode.RESULT_OK) {
            if (Consts.DEBUG) {
                Log.d(TAG, "completed RestoreTransactions request");
            }
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "completed RestoreTransactions request " + responseCode, 2000).show();
            // Update the shared preferences so that we don't perform
            // a RestoreTransactions again.
            SharedPreferences prefs = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor edit = prefs.edit();
            edit.putBoolean(DB_INITIALIZED, true);
            edit.commit();
            } else {
            if (Consts.DEBUG) {
                Log.d(TAG, "RestoreTransactions error: " + responseCode);
            }
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "RestoreTransactions error: " + responseCode, 2000).show();
            }
        }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:**

This is from the official android developers website:

```
/**
* Request type is RESTORE_TRANSACTIONS
*/
  Bundle request = makeRequestBundle("RESTORE_TRANSACTIONS");
  request.putLong(REQUEST_NONCE, mNonce);
  Bundle response = mService.sendBillingRequest(request);
  // Do something with this response.
}
```

You should read the documentation under the headline "Restoring transaction information (RESTORE_TRANSACTIONS)" which you can find here:

http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/v2/billing_integrate.html

Comment: so you mean i need to send this as SKU instead of "android.test.purchased" ?

Comment: yes! ;) This is the test SKU if your In-App purchase will be refunded.

Comment: But i dont want a refund, i want to restore my purchased item

Comment: Sorry, I thought you meant refund with restore. I updated my code and I think this is what you are looking for

Comment: The code that you have given is for Version 3 and what i am working on is version 2,